# What happens when I summon "Gameciel the Sea Turtle Kaiju" to my opponent's field by tributing their "Prank-Kids Battle Butler"?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

As many people are aware of, the removal of monsters by tributing them for Kaiju monsters, or "Kaijuing", is a relatively common way of dealing with threatening monsters that are hard to get rid of.

In this situation, Battle Butler has a relatively unique floating effect, however. A line in [Prank-Kids Battle Butler](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Prank-Kids_Battle_Butler)'s effect reads:

> If this card in your possession is sent to your GY by your opponent's card: You can target 1 non-Fusion Monster in your GY; Special Summon it.

This line is odd, because instead of saying battle or card effect, it just says "card".

When I tribute a Battle Butler to summon [Gameciel, the Sea Turtle Kaiju](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Gameciel,_the_Sea_Turtle_Kaiju) (or any other Kaiju), does it's floating effect activate? It has been tributed by a card in my hand, but now that it's summoned to the opponent's field, it's "their card".

Comment: As a historical note: Before Kaiju's, [Lava Golem](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Lava_Golem) was used with the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no specific ruling issued for this sort of interaction yet, but to the best of my knowledge I would say:

## No, the effect of Battle Butler will not activate.

So, there's a little bit of a distinction we have to make here to understand why this one works the way it does. It's a bit nuanced.

**Gameciel is not sending Battle Butler to the GY in this scenario. The player who summons Gameciel is tributing it as part of a summoning procedure.**

This is in important distinction; Gameciel itself is not tributing the card; you, the player are tributing it. Semantically, it's the same reason why the monsters used for a Tribute Summon, or tributed to summon something like Raviel, Lord of Phantasms are not considered to be sent to the GY by the monster they were tributed to summon.

Comment: I am not sure @squid . The card itself is the one that states that "You can ... by tributing one...", so it is the card's the one causing the tribute. The game rules allow players to tribute their own monsters for tribute summons, but you can't do that with Opponent's monsters... it is Gameciel's effect that allows you to do that, and thus why it triggers Battle Buttler

Comment: More details on the [Kaiju rulings](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Kaiju), specifically the first: *"[...] 1 monster in your opponent's Monster Zone is Tributed as a procedure to Special Summon this card by this effect, then the Special Summon is performed."* Which states clearly that the tribute is caused by the card effect.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, emphasis on the "as a procedure to Special Summon" in the text you've quoted. This is not an effect that is being applied to the opponent's monster, but an effect that allows Gameciel to be summoned by a procedure.

Comment: How I interpret it is that the procedure is due to the *card's effect*. Normally, the rules don't allow players to tribute opponent's monsters, but Gameciel does... I see your point, though, your answer made me question if mine is correct... I'll consult with some friends of mine that are Judges and will get back to you :)

Comment: Actually, @DarkCygnus, it HAS to be the case that a monster effect isn't being applied to the tributed monster, otherwise monsters that are unaffected by monster effects would not be legal tributes for Kaijus. Is that not accurate?

Comment: That is what I'm questioning haha, I *think* that a monster unaffected by other card effects should not be a valid target... but I am dubious now... great discussion that came from this question, huh? Will call my Judge friends and ping you :)

Comment: So, checked with my Judge friend and it turns out it *does* trigger Battle Butler's effect. Gameciel's effect is, in fact, more a summoning condition... but it's due to Gameciel's effect that you are allowed to sacrifice an Opponent's monster. The Kaiju's effect may well not be Trigger, ignition, etc (as specified in the rulings), but it is a card effect nonetheless... and without Gameciel you wouldn't be able to sacrifice Battle Butler (thus Gameciel is the source of you being able to do so)... will try to find some ruling or backup and enhance my answer. Great discussion :)

Comment: Your judge friend is still wrong; even if Gameciel's effect is what allows you to tribute the monster, Gameciel itself isn't the thing tributing the monster, the player is. If we're going this route, you'd have to say the same thing for something like Chimeratech Fortress Dragon.

Comment: Well, I'll stop commenting under your answer as we are making noise, but my friend is Judge for some reason haha. This is a not so trivial question, to be honest, and I take it one may be dubious. Wen I get some time I'll dig deeper into this.

Comment: I think that this is the correct ruling, but I would rather not accept the answer until there is at least some bit of outside evidence. This makes more sense, because the card itself isn't doing the tributing, but the player. Monsters that are unaffected by card effects can be tributed for Kaijus, so it doesn't count as a card effect.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tribute a Battle Butler to summon a Kaiju, does it's floating effect activate? It has been tributed by a card in my hand, but now that it's summoned to the opponent's field, it's "their card".

Actually, it is still *your card* (that is, you are the **owner** of the card).

The thing is that your Kaiju is now under your opponent's **control**. Both are different things. From the wiki page on [Owner](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Owner), emphasis mine:

> Owner or original owner (元々)持ち主 motomoto mochinushi) refers to the player that originally possesses a card. **The card's owner is distinct from its controller, as while the controller of a card may change, its owner cannot.**

So the Kaiju is *your* card, and thus your opponent's Battle Buttler effect will trigger.

Here is a [related question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/42144/22373) that I answered where the Owner vrs. Controller difference is explained.